# ng-show not working after setting checkbox value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I have a checkbox which shows/hides a graph when clicked. When I change its clicked attribute in controller, button gets clicked but the graph does not become visible.

The html part I use is below;

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      Graph
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="visibleGraph" id="graph_check">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-show="visibleGraph">
   <div class="panel-heading">Graph</div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="graph_data"
         chart-labels="graph_labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
         chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="chartClicked">
      </canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here how I set its value in controller;

```
document.getElementById("graph_check").checked=true;
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why didn't use `ng-model` instead of `id`?

Comment: @Hadi don't suggest such things, this is not angular way of doing it. Though it would work, just have to run digest cycle manually.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating `scope`/`DOM` value directly from jQuery would not intimate AngularJS digest cycle system to update bindings on page, in such cases you have to run digest cycle manually (though updating `scope`/`DOM` from controller is anti-pattern).

You could directly set `visibleGraph` value, in-spite of setting value in DOM.

```
$scope.visibleGraph = true
```

Also I'd highly recommend to read up on [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/2435473)